# responseText from $.get in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

`var response = $.get(url);`

and I want to get responseText from the returned `response` object.  And it is there.  All the solutions I've looked up on stackoverflow say to change my ajax request, but the data is definitely there in the object.  How can I get responseText out of this object?  I dont want to change the above code.

Comment: Sounds like an XY Problem to me: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) returns a [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object

```
var response = $.get(url);

response.done(function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```